# How to read .XML file in XNA?

Tags: c#, xml, xna

I've created a simple .XML file to load a level in my xna game.
The xml tells the game where the player's start position is and the position for two walls.

The problem is that I don't know how to create the wall objects and put them into a list.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="MyDataTypes.LevelValues">
    <player1x> -5.5</player1x>
    <player1y> -4.5</player1y>
    <Walls>
      <wall>
        <startx>1</startx>
        <endx>2</endx>
      </wall>
      <wall>
        <startx>3</startx>
        <endx>4</endx>
      </wall>
    </Walls>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

My levelValues:

```
 public class LevelValues
    {
        public float player1x;
        public float player1y;
        public List<Wall> Walls {get;set;}

        public LevelValues()
        {
            Walls = new List<Wall>();
        }        
    }
```

Wall:

```
public class Wall
{
    public float startx;
    public float endx;
}
```

And calling this from loadContent in game1.cs:

```
LevelValues level;
level = Content.Load<LevelValues>(@"Level\leveltest");
```

When running the game player1x and player1y gets their values but, ofcourse, it crashes on "walls". So, how do I create two wall objects, assign their values and put them in a list ( walls)?

Comment: You can save `LevelValues` first and see how `Walls` looks like (I have no idea how `List<Wall>` is serialized). You could possible create a simple *level editor* together with the game, to avoid human mistakes.

Comment: I don't understand =/ levelValues should contain all info from the XML file. There is no need for a level editor at this point, the game will only contain two levels for now. Good idea though.

Comment: How do you *save* level? Are you creating xml-files manually? By typing? Do you know how to read xml? Do you know how to save xml? Do you use `XmlSerializer/Deserializer` or what? I see you are using `Content.Load<>`, can't you generate level and then do something like `Content.Save<>` and see xml-file for yourself?

Comment: I don't save the level at the moment and I don't think I'll have to save it at all. Yes, i'm creating the xml manually by typing. No serialization at all right now. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying your list items correctly.  Change your `<wall></wall>` tags to `<Item></Item>`.

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/08/12/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-intermediateserializer.aspx) for more details on XNA's intermediate XML serializer.

Comment: Ok, but how does xna know it's a wall object? If i just want to add primitives to a list that would do it, but it has to create the wall objects first and then put them into a list.

Comment: It knows it's a wall object because it's populating a `List<Wall>`.

Comment: Also, please read the linked article.  Note the section on "Polymorphic Types."

Comment: That was perfect! Somehow I skipped that part redaing the article. Thanks mate!